# PYTHON: Encountering import error when trying to import YMODEM from xmodem

Tags: python, modem, xmodem, zmodem

Hello I'm trying to `import YMODEM from xmodem` and encountering `Import` error. But if I `import xmodem from XMODEM,` I don't see any Import Error.

```
from xmodem import YMODEM
ImportError: cannot import name 'YMODEM' from 'xmodem'
```

I would like to transfer data using `YMODEM` protocol. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,
-Indra.

Tried:

```
from xmodem import YMODEM
ImportError: cannot import name 'YMODEM' from 'xmodem'
```

Expected:
Need to send file using `YMODEM` protocol. My understanding is `xmodem` package has the support for `YMODEM`.

Comment: If you're using [this module](https://github.com/tehmaze/xmodem), it only implements plain Xmodem. There is no Ymodem support available.

Comment: Right.  You have the source code -- go look.  It supports XMODEM and XMODEM1k.  If that's not the module you're using, then you need to tell us exactly which one you have.

Comment: from modem import XMODEM